# How to propegate exceptions with the Python C API?

Tags: python, c++, error-handling, python-c-api

I'm working on a project which requires me to interface C(++) code with Python. Now, in general, this is going quite well, but whenever I run into a bug, instead of python/C printing the exception/error that's occurring, it just quits the program as it functioned correctly. As you might imagine, this makes debugging rather difficult, since I have nothing to go on besides "There's some error somewhere".

Hence I ask this question: What's the proper way to propagate exceptions that occur, or at least get them to print?

I did try placing every function of the C program in the construct defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception), but could not get it to work.

Comment: I don't know about how you would do what you are asking for - but you probably cannot pass C++ exceptions through C code, though that's likely an implementation detail. Can you write a wrapper for those C++ functions that simply catches exceptions and prints them before terminating?

Comment: The code I'm writing is in C++. I did try wrapping the functions I use in the code provided in the link (I think that's what it's supposed to do), but haven't had any success.

Comment: If your code is C++, have you considered to replace the Python C API with, e.g., pybind11? It wraps python exceptions to C++ exceptions. https://gist.github.com/pasbi/aefb4c568e2f323f3a3d7bd322de6e9c

Comment: To clarify, in the extension module, you catch the c++ exceptions in c++ and raise python exceptions. The two are fundamentally different, but you hide that with the wrapper. Additionally, I will note that you can debug in python or c++, depending on where the error is happening.

Comment: @KennyOstrom The module I'm working on has to deal with the GIL which is causing some bugs, so the debugging can only happen in python, since the interface between C and python is important here. C++ exceptions are being raised, but then ignored by python. I'm looking for a way to throw a python exception whenever a C++ exception occurs so that I can see the C++ exception and figure out where the bug is located.